# Exclude filter not working for filevault-package-maven-plugin

Tags: adobe, aem

I have a content package with nodes I would like to exclude when this package is installed on AEM 6.5. The exclude configuration is defined in filter.xml (META-INF/vault/filter.xml).

Below is a representation of my filter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/amzn-biz">
        <exclude pattern="/apps/amzn-biz/i18n(.*)"/>
    </filter>
    <filter root="/apps/sling"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

My pom.xml has below configuration

```
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
            <!-- V A U L T   P A C K A G E   P L U G I N S                              -->
            <!-- ====================================================================== -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
                <artifactId>filevault-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <group>amzn-biz</group>
                    <acHandling>merge_preserve</acHandling>
                    <packageType>content</packageType>
                    <embeddeds>
                        <embedded>
                            <groupId>com.amazon.business</groupId>
                            <artifactId>amzn-biz-foundation.core</artifactId>
                            <target>/apps/amzn-biz/install</target>
                        </embedded>
                    </embeddeds>
                    <subPackages>
                        <subPackage>
                            <groupId>com.adobe.cq</groupId>
                            <artifactId>core.wcm.components.all</artifactId>
                            <filter>true</filter>
                        </subPackage>
                        <subPackage>
                            <groupId>com.adobe.cq</groupId>
                            <artifactId>core.wcm.components.examples</artifactId>
                            <filter>true</filter>
                        </subPackage>
                    </subPackages>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I have tried multiple things by changing my exclude patterns to .*/i18n.* but it has not worked for me.

I have also tried adding filterSource to filevault-package-maven-plugin configuration but then i get the error Project contains filter.xml in META-INF/vault but also specifies a filter source.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I have tried different rules but with no luck, the i18n is still in the ui.apps content package!

Answer (score 5):

You have to remove the nodes from the content package. You should not have any content in your content package, that is not explicitly covered by a filter-rule.

Your problem is weird backward-compatibility. At least in CQ5 were no filter-modes (`mode="replace|merge|update"`) yet. In those days the rule was, that all content covered by a filter-rule is replaced. All other content is merged. When the filter-modes were introduced, they became non-intuitive but backward-compatible. In your case the i18n folder is merged.

**Rule of thumb: A content package that is imported and exported again should be identical.** (this would not be the case for you)

For more details see the table at https://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault/filter.html#Usage_for_Import.2FInstallation for more information. For your i18n folder it says:

> *nodes which are ancestors of covered rules*: deserialized from content package (for backwards compatibility reasons), nodes which are
>   not ancestors of covered rules: not touched. One should not rely on
>   this behaviour, i.e. all items in the content package should always be
>   covered by some filter rule to make the behaviour more explicit.

Comment: I do not get it, so, the only solution is to delete the local i18n? I would like to keep it as a backup in the development phase, after that it will be unversioned.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be relating to <packageType>**content**</packageType> instead of  filter.xml.  This type cannot have sub-packages nor embedded bundles.  If <embeddeds> and <subPackages> are needed for the project, use <packageType>**mixed**</packageType> will reduce chance of unexpected build and installation behaviors.

The list of package types and behaviors are as following:

- **application**:  Package consists pure application content (aka. /apps/*).  Does not contain any subpackages nor OSGi configuration or bundles.
- **content**:  Package consists only of content and user defined configuration.  Does not contain any subpackages nor OSGi configuration or bundles.
- **container**:  Package only contains sub packages and OSGi configuration and bundles.
- **mixed**:  Catch all type for a combination of the above.

More details can be found at http://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault-package-maven-plugin/generate-metadata-mojo.html#packageType